# PDO How to pass on the ID Key

Tags: mysql, pdo

I know there is something basic staring me in the face here. I could do this in mysql but in PDO I can't get the Key(id) of a row to pass on to the next page. When a user clicks on "More Details" on a row I want it to open a page with all the details for that row plus the full size photo. It is currently opening the page, putting Key = (the right number) in the address bar and writing "no rows found" in the page. What am I doing wrong and is there a better way I should be doing this?

This page has the rows from the search:

```
 <?php
  $STM = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM engravers WHERE Country = :Country");
  if(isset($_POST['dropdown'])){
  $Country = $_POST['dropdown'];
  }else{
  $Country = "Australia";
  }

 $STM->bindParam(':Country', $Country, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $STM->execute();                    
 $row= $STM->fetchAll();
 $img_url = "http://www.engravedstamps.net/images/";
 if(count($row)){
 echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='0>";

 foreach($row as $data){
         $Key = $data['Key'];
         echo "<tr><th>Key</th><th>Country</th><th>Year</th><th>Description</th><th>Image</th>     </tr>";
         echo "<tr><td>".$data['Key']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$data['Country']. "</td>";
          echo "<td>".$data['Year']."</td>";
           echo "<td>".$data['Description']."</td>";
           echo "<td>"."<img src='$img_url".$data['Images']."'<br /><br />"."</td>";
     ?>

    <td><a href="more.php?Key=<? echo $data['Key'];?>">More Details</td>
            <?

    echo "</tr>";
     }
     }else {
     echo 'no row found';
     }
     ?>
```

That page seems to work and should hand the Key to this page which is basically a rejig of the one before. I haven't rebuilt the table at the bottom yet.

```
 <?php

 $STM = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM engravers WHERE Key = :Key");
 if(isset($_GET['Key'])){
 $Key = $_Get['Key'];
 }else{
 $Key = "Oops";
 }

 $STM->bindParam(':Key', $Key, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $STM->execute();                    
 $row= $STM->fetchAll();
 $img_url = "http://www.engravedstamps.net/images/";
 if(count($row)){

 echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='0>";

 foreach($row as $data){
                 echo "<tr><th>Key</th><th>Country</th><th>Year</th><th>Description</th><th>Image</th>   </tr>";
         echo "<tr><td>".$data['Key']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$data['Country']. "</td>";
          echo "<td>".$data['Year']."</td>";
           echo "<td>".$data['Description']."</td>";
           echo "<td>"."<img src='$img_url".$data['StampImages']."'<br /><br />"."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
     }
     }else {
     echo 'no row found';
     }

     ?>
```

I've spent all day on this which will teach me a lesson for thinking this was a simple part of the operation. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code is so messy, i passed whole part of it. Dont know may be help `$Key = $_Get['Key'];` must be `$Key = $_GET['Key'];`

Answer (score 0):

`$_Get` should be `$_GET` when you're copying your Key:

Change

```
$Key = $_Get['Key'];
```

To

```
$Key = $_GET['Key'];
```

And, to answer *is there a better way I should be doing this?*:

You're using PDO: Good

You're using prepared statements with bindValue for user input: Good

You're checking if user input exists before attempting to use it: Good

You're using `$Key = "Oops";` in replacement of no Key: Not good, this converts to an integer value of 1.

I'd say you're doing things right, the main thing that I would do differently is: I would have my database logic elsewhere (separate file/class), as I do not like to mix display logic with database logic.  However, this is a design decision and not something you're doing wrong.

Comment: I've been staring at that one all day but unfortunately fixing it doesn't change the result. Darn! I thought that was it.

Comment: Try doing a `var_dump($Key);` before using it.  Also try `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: var_dump gives me a message "string(1) "4" no row found". It could be from the previous page. I've just noticed that the printed table is missing the first entry for every country. As I'm just trying to print one line here and the code is pretty similar the problems look like they are the same. Darned if I can see it though."4" is the Key for the row clicked.

Comment: My reading on other posts is suggesting that I can't bind the Key in this way as it is the $_Get value and is also the name of the column.

Comment: Have you tried casting it to an integer directly?  I was assuming using `PDO::PARAM_INT` would force the cast.  Fe. `$Key = (int)$_GET['Key'];`

Comment: That doesn't seem to change things. The Get is working but I think the problem is that it ends up as $Key but then we try to go back to Key for the param binding which introduces another $Key. I'll work around that for a while.